# Xcode Swift 3 TableView cellselection

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, tableview, cell

Hy,

Currently I'm working on an application which makes use of a tableview. Everything was working fine until I ran it one more time and suddenly, I couldn't select any cells of my tableview any more. I retried several times (cleaning up and rerunning) but this didn't work. After several tries, I found out I could select the cell but only after holding it for 5 seconds... I already tried to find a solution but other peoples problems involved a GestureRecognizer, something I don't make use of in the particular view... (When the problem appeared, it appeared in every view that made use of a tableview or a collectionview so I don't think it's a problem with the code.)

Comment: if there is any gesture then please make it as nil. I think its's problem of tap gesture.

Comment: is your UITableView added to an UIScrollView?

Comment: Please post the minimum code required to reproduce the issue. Pasting 460 lines of code will make difficult for others to reproduce.

Comment: I didn't add any gestures to this project, my tableview isn't part of a scrollview and it's not a fault with the code I just posted it if you would see a problem... The problem just occured without editing any of the code so...

Answer (score 1):

It's not the question you asked, but here's how you can simplify the blurEffect selection.  You're repeating the same code every time - so how about his...

```
    switch typesearch
    {
    case "bakery":
        resourceName = "67420429-bakery-wallpapers.jpg"
    case "bank":
        resourceName = "bank.jpg"
    case "bowling_alley":
        resourceName = "bowling-alley.jpg"
    case "restaurant", "cafe,bar", "cafe":
        resourceName = "restaurant-den-haag.jpg"
    case "casino":
        resourceName = "casino.jpg"
    case "church", "city_hall", "embassy":
        resourceName = "church.jpg"
    case "gym":
        resourceName = "gym.jpg"
    case "museum":
        resourceName = "museum.jpg"
    case "night_club":
        resourceName = "night_club.jpg"
    case "park":
        resourceName = "park.jpg"
    case "school":
        resourceName = "school"
    case "spa":
        resourceName = "spa.jpg"
    case "park":
        resourceName = "park.jpg"
    case "stadium":
        resourceName = "stadium.jpg"
    case "university":
        resourceName = "university.jpg"
    case "zoo":
        resourceName = "zoo.jpg"
    default:
        resourceName = "defaultImage.jpg"

    }

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    Backgroundimage.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: resourceName)
    Backgroundimage.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```